# How do I store settings to server?

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, storage, android-settings

I've a fragment settings with a lot of fields regarding user profile, like height, weight, etc. Any best practice for saving that data to my server via API? When is the right moment to submit the request for update (PUT) after the user have changed something? I've no "save button", so where's the trigger event? Every single change? In case of error, should I notify via Toast or something like that? Is this a job for a sync adapter or what? I'm a little bit confused. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to make the less possible calls.

If you don't have a save button, i understand that changes are saved immediately, so, you should make the call when the user leaves the settings screen, but taking care of the app being closed.

You should always notify the user about the changes being saved with a progress bar or something.

And yes, in case of error, show a toast, or maybe an alertDialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: best possible solution